# access external resources using phonegap in BlackBerry

Tags: cordova, blackberry-webworks

I have this simple index.html

```html
<div class="app">
<h1>Test</h1>
<img src="http://ilbesculpi.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/4584195698_9593b16574.jpg" width="80%" />
</div>
```

But the external image is not displayed. Instead, I got a red cross.

Thing I've tried:

1.- Add domain to whitelisting in config.xml

```xml
<access origin="*" />
<access uri="*" subdomains="true" />
<access uri="http://ilbesculpi.com" subdomains="true" />
```

2.- Add internet access in config.xml

```xml
<rim:permissions>
<rim:permit>access_internet</rim:permit>
<rim:permit>access_shared</rim:permit>
<rim:permit>read_geolocation</rim:permit>
</rim:permissions>
```

3.- Give priority to WIFI

```xml
<rim:connection timeout="60000">
<id>BIS-B</id>
<id>TCP_WIFI</id>
<id>TCP_CELLULAR</id>
<id>MDS</id>
<id>WAP2</id>
<id>WAP</id>
</rim:connection>
```

But none of this works. Any help?

Comment: What version of phonegap are you using?
Which BlackBerry OS are you targetting (BBOS, Tablet, BB10) ?

Comment: Sorry I didn't mentioned. I'm targeting BBOS 6 & 7. I'm using current PhoneGap version (2.9.0). It works well on browser and Ripple Emulator, but not on the device itself. I get the same issue if I try to access external content via $.ajax. So, it looks like a security issue or something that I've to put on the config... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I hope you got a solution for the problem. If so, please paste it as answer here.

And, I have the same problem.

To solve it you can add the `<feature>` within your `<access>` tag-

you can find the instructions here...
http://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/feature_element_834678_11.html